# error converting a String into a float java

Tags: java, servlets, floating-point

```
String initial_price = request.getParameter("initial_price");
    float initial_price_float = 0;
    try {
        initial_price_float = Float.parseFloat(initial_price);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                session.setAttribute("message", "Wrong input");
    }
```

The piece of code written above gives me this error, but I am pretty sure I have written the right number. How can I solve it?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1008)
java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:452)
servlet.AddProduct.doPost(AddProduct.java:114)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: what is the input ? make sure you trim() it

Comment: You are getting a `NullPointerException` because it looks like your `initial_price` variable is not defined.  What does your request object look like?

Comment: did you try to debug or to print the value `initial_price` before you call `Float.parseFloat(initial_price);`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that initial_price is not nul because I insert a value into the form..

Comment: You are never sure unless you print it or see it in debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass a `null` string into `parseFloat`.

Per `parseFloat`'s [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29):

```
@throws NullPointerException  if the string is null
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(..)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java) code:

`in = in.trim();` // don't fool around with white space.
                       // throws NullPointerException if `null`
Make sure input is not `null`.